# Visual Studio clears command line arguments when begins to run

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2019, command-line-arguments, vcxproj, visual-c++-2013

In my solution, I have a Visual C++ project which uses

Platform Toolset = Visual Studio 2013 (v120)

which I am opening in Visual Studio 2019.

If I edit the Project Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging > Command arguments to ***something*** , and do OK it goes well, as if I open this dialog again is everything OK.

[image]

But when I run the application, the Command Arguments got cleared, for the specified configuration, as the same odd behavior happens both in Release and Debug Configurations. This way I can not use VS interface to parameterize the command input.

The moment I hit the Play button, the parameterization has disappeared:

[image]

Help, please.

***UPDATE:***

It seems to be an extension causing the strange behavior. I disabled every extension I could, and the behavior is not happening now. When I have time, I will try to cherry pick what extension is annoying me and give more updates.

***UPDATE 2:***

I just enabled extensions by blocks of a few alphabetically and ended up with all of them being enabled, and seen VS is just behaving well. I am believing the fact of disabling some extension has put things back on track.

Comment: It does not make sense that when you "run" it it would reset the actual project file content. Have you tried building with "verbose" mode and looked to see. I don't think there is much we can do here to help you.

Comment: Sounds like a timestamp issue with some extension. Portugal recently switched from standard time to daylight savings time. That's always an event that has the potential to break timestamp-sensitive code logic. Potential extension candidates are either those that modify the .vcxproj files, or an SCM integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to me today again. I did some disk cleaning some days ago, I may have touched something in Visual Studio 2019.

Now, I was getting the same problem. This time, after seeing VS having several times this bad behavior, I tried to change the command line arguments, DID NOT start debugging, then I restarted VS, started Debugging again and now it seems to do what is supposed, not to clear my command line arguments customization.

**UPDATE:** this is happening again. It happens when it is not the first time I click "Start Debugging" after starting Visual Studio. So this implies I will have to restart VS almost every time I want to start debugging, for not getting the command line arguments cleared. ☹

Answer (score 2):

I just uninstalled an extension named "Smart Command Line Arguments" and now things seem to work fine.

May be I was using wrongly, I don't know.

Now I will be continuing my work, and if I don't find any problems, I will accept my present answer.